# Twilio's functions- is there a list of npm modules available

Tags: twilio

In Twilio's function configurations you can add nodejs module dependencies. However, there's no way to tell what dependencies are allowed until I enter them. 
Then it just says "not found" and won't let me use them.

Is there a list of modules Twilio allows somewhere? Right now I'm just blindly guessing based on popular modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [limitations for npm modules on Twilio Functions are listed here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/packages#limitations). They are:

> - Native Packages Not Supported - Functions does not provide a C/C++ compliler required to complie native addon modules. This means modules that depend on [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) can not be installed to Functions.
> - 20 NPM Modules Limit - During public beta, developers will be limited to installing 20 NPM modules. To raise these limits during public beta, please contact Twilio Support.

Let me know if that helps at all.